# Value attribute is not Displaying when inspecting an element on Google Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem figuring out why does value attribute is missing in chrome though the value is visible on the front end.

On Internet explorer, I have this sample code snippet:

```
<INPUT id=txtTextbox1 value=samplevalue name=txtTextbox1>
```

On chrome (value attribute is not displaying):

```
<input name="txtTextbox1" type="text" id="txtTextbox1">
```

I have no Idea what is happening. 
Are there any javascript code that will trigger the issue on chrome? Please help.

Comment: Yeah. But the first markup is working on IE

Comment: If your `value=" "`, then in chrome it will is not showing, if `value="some value"` then you can able to see the attribute in debugger.